# Error in PayPal live transaction in android

Tags: live, android-sdk-2.3, paypal

[image]

i am using android sdk for paypal transactions. it works well for Sanbox test account and it give a proper response from paypal, but when i change the configuration from sandbox to Live and change the client_id for live account, and when i login to pay in android application, it login succesful but after that given this error. i dont know what the error is this, what should i do for live transaction,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks its **resolved** now with `sdk - 2.12.5`

test it with

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5')
```

from [this link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/228)

> I have updated the okhttp version to latest stable release in v2.12.5.
>   Can you please update to latest version and confirm if you are now not
>   getting this exception.
>
> I was hardly able to reproduce this issue on any device, and so, would
>   need your help fixing this issue. I will keep an eye on this issue
>   promptly, and get it sorted out soon :+1:
>
> Thanks for helping all !

Comment: i contact with paypal support team say that you are paying your self